# Logstash and Jboss

Tags: jboss, jvm, logstash

I have newly setup a JBOSS JVM server and would like to use ELK to visualize the Server Host Usage Metrics. Though I can see there are server logs but seem are not showing the Host Usage Metrics, i.g. cpu usage, disk usage, heap usage, etc.

Would anyone can tell me how can I collect these metrics with logstash and any simple conf file to collect them?

Comment: Maybe Collectd, see https://mtalavera.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/monitoring-with-collectd-and-kibana/

Comment: Thanks. However, isn't that similar to topbeat and what will be the difference between topbeat and collectd?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a pipeline of server metrics directly into Elasticsearch using [Topbeat](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/beats/topbeat). All you have to do is define your Elasticsearch instance as the output in the configuration file. Or, you could output to Logstash.
If you're using Docker, there is a nice [image](http://logz.io/blog/application-performance-monitoring-docker-elk-stack/) by Logz.io that uses collectl and RSYSLOG:
`docker pull logzio/logzio-perfagent`

Comment: Isn't that Topbeat collect metrics over the whole server instead of the single JBOSS application?